# iPad SplitView Controller with different detailviewcontrollers based upon item selection?

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

What is the best way to support multiple detailed view controllers in an iPad SplitViewController?

I want different detailViewController types to be displayed depending on which row is selected from the RootViewController.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hm, the split view controller is meant to support multiple detail views selected by the master (root) view.

Please check the "[MultipleDetailViews](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MultipleDetailViews/Introduction/Intro.html)" sample code found in Xcode.